# How to focus the embed video

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to focus on the embedded video by pressing a tab,
if once click a video after that the tabbing will flow but there is no way to come out of the video.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "body" ).on("keypress", function( event ){
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        $("video").trigger("click");
    }
});
```